# TorchServe shows `Console contains an invalid element or attribute "JsonTemplateLayout"`

Tags: log4j, torchserve

I'm trying to configure TorchServe to loggin in JSON:

### The first attempt with JsonTemplateLayout

I've added `log4j2.xml` config with `JsonTemplateLayout`:

```xml
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json"/>
</Console>
```

Then I've run the command below:

```bash
torchserve \
--start \
--model-store model_store \
--models doc_model=doc_model.mar \
--ncs \
--ts-config ./src/ts.config \
--log-config ./src/log4j2.xml
```

and have got the warning and error:

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2023-05-23 18:52:00,570 main ERROR Console contains an invalid element or attribute "JsonTemplateLayout"
```

### The second attempt with JsonLayout

`log4j2.xml`:

```xml
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <JSONLayout compact="true" complete="false" eventEol="true"/>
</Console>
```

The same command to run torchserve as above also failed. The message is:

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
2023-05-23 18:56:08,650 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout for element JSONLayout: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/FilterProvider java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/FilterProvider
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout.<init>(JsonLayout.java:159)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout.<init>(JsonLayout.java:71)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout$Builder.build(JsonLayout.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout$Builder.build(JsonLayout.java:79)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
        at org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager.<init>(PluginsManager.java:18)
        at org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager.<clinit>(PluginsManager.java:17)
        at org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer.main(ModelServer.java:85)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 27 more

2023-05-23 18:56:08,656 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout for element JSONLayout: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:236)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:134)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1120)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1045)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1037)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:651)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:247)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:293)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:626)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:699)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:716)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:270)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:245)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
        at org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager.<init>(PluginsManager.java:18)
        at org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager.<clinit>(PluginsManager.java:17)
        at org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer.main(ModelServer.java:85)
```

Could anyone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

The sources I've researched for the task:

1. [Log4j Layouts docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)
2. [Logging in TorchServe](https://pytorch.org/serve/logging.html)